# $\phi_n: \mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ is isomorphism when $n$ even, birational when $n$ odd?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\phi_n: \mathbb{A}^1\rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2$ be defined as $x\mapsto (x^2,x^n)$. Then when $n$ is odd, $n=2k+1$, so I can produce rational inverse $(x,y)\mapsto \frac{y}{x^k}$ regular at everywhere except $(0,0)$.

But when $n$ is even, how do I produce an inverse morphism and show the image of $\phi_n, C=\{y=x^{\frac{n}{2}}\}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$?

Answer (score 1):

You can't, because $\phi_n$ is not an isomorphism for $n$ even. If $\phi_n$ were an isomorphism, it would induce an isomorphism on coordinate algebras. But $k[C]\cong k[x,y]/(y=x^{n/2})\cong k[x]$, and the map on the coordinate algebra side is $k[x]\to k[x]$ by $x\mapsto x^2$, which is not an isomorphism because it misses $x$.